# When deploying Kubernetes with Ansible, how to specify the version?

Tags: deployment, ansible, kubernetes

Using Ansible for deploying Kubernetes according to the official [contrib repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ansible), it installed a Kubernetes 1.2 for me, although 1.3.x is current.  How can I specify the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, one could simply add

```
kube_version: 1.3.5
```

to the `all.yml` file.  However, at least on RedHat, this does nothing.  This is because other settings affect the Kubernetes version number, too.  In case of RedHat,

```
kube_version: 1.3.0
kube_source_type: distribution-rpm
kube_rpm_url_base: https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/kubernetes/1.3.0/0.2.git507d3a7.fc26/x86_64
kube_rpm_url_sufix: 1.3.0-0.2.git507d3a7.fc26.x86_64.rpm
```

does the trick of upgrading the current playbooks (as of August 2016) to Kubernetes 1.3.0.  (The `kube_version` may be even superfluous here.)  Another possibility, which should work for all flavours of Linux, is

```
kube_version: 1.3.5
kube_source_type: github-release
```

However, at least as of August 2016, this leads to a deployment error, possibly because the directory structure of the Kubernetes source tree has changed between 1.2.0 and 1.3.5.

Other possible combinations of these settings can be found in the comments  of [Kubernetes' `main.yml` file](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ansible/roles/kubernetes/defaults/main.yml), however, all this trouble suggests that it is best to wait for the Ansible Kubernetes files to be updated instead of forcing a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Default value for roles is `kube_version: 1.2.4`.
You can override it by calling: `./deploy-cluster.sh -e kube_version=1.3.5`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Please be patient with me … as soon as I re-create our cluster, I check this!